# Xamarin iOS Simulator Black Screen After Xcode 11 Update

Tags: troubleshooting, ios, xcode, visual-studio-2017

I am using a Windows PC and Xamarin, Visual Studio 15.9.16, and have recently updated Xcode to version 11 on my Mac.

After the Xcode update, my Xamarin.Forms app never loads and the iOS Simulator simply shows a black screen after launching. I have tried multiple other form factor simulators, but they all show the same symptoms.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Same problem here, ¿Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after a few hours.

My issue was at the Info.plist, below what I did on Visual studio for windows:

1. Right click on the info.plist and select Open with
2. Choose iOS manifest editor
3. Click on the tab visual effect
4. Go to the Launch Images
5. Make sure the option Source and Launch Screen are set up properlly
6. Clean your entire solution
7. Rebuild project
8. Try again

in my case Source was set as none.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrsHr.png)